# Italicizing Java text box

Tags: javascript, italics

I need to update a code by having the name appear in italics in the following sentences.
Where in the innerHTML would I place the   tags?

```
`enter code here`
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Greetings
  </title>
  <meta charset="us-ascii">
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>Greetings</h2>
  <p>
   Enter your name:
   <input type="text" id="nameBox" size=12 value="">
  </p>
  <input type="button" value="Click for Greeting"
   onclick="
    document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
     'Hello '
     + document.getElementById('nameBox').value
     + ', welcome to my page.<br>Do you mind if I call you '
     + document.getElementById('nameBox').value
     + '?';
    ">
   <hr>
   <div id="outputDiv">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What following sentences? What name? Are you using Java, or JavaScript? Please elaborate more, and tag accordingly.

Comment: <html>
 <head>
   <title> Greetings </title>
   <meta charset="us-ascii">
 </head>

 <body>
   <h2>Greetings</h2>

   <p>
     Enter your name: <input type="text" id="nameBox" size=12 value="">
   </p>
   <input type="button" value="Click for Greeting"
          onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
                     'Hello ' + document.getElementById('nameBox').value + 
                     ', welcome to my page.<br>Do you mind if I call you ' +
                     document.getElementById('nameBox').value + '?';"> 
   <hr>
   <div id="outputDiv"></div>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: Please don't enter code in the comment section as it is unreadable. Instead edit your original post and add your formatted code there to the original question.

Comment: You can format the code as a code block by prefixing four spaces to each line.

Comment: ... which of course assumes there _are_ lines and it's not just an unreadable blob of tags running like a freight train across the whole screen

Comment: I dearly regret going on and indenting your code to reveal... an immense `onclick`. This attribute's been deprecated for years

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following code, it should make the reply italicized. FYI all changes to the look of the output can be done using CSS (the style tags). Also, it is a good idea to keep HTML, JavaScript, and CSS components isolated from one another.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
        <title> Greetings</title>
        <meta charset="us-ascii">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function greeting(){
                document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
                'Hello <span class="name">'
                + document.getElementById('nameBox').value
                + '</span>, welcome to my page.<br>Do you mind if I call you <span class="name">'
                + document.getElementById('nameBox').value
                + '</span>?';
           }
        </script>
         <style type="text/css">
            span.name{
                font-style:italic;
            }
         </style>
     </head>
     <body>
         <h2>Greetings</h2>
         <p>
            Enter your name:<input type="text" id="nameBox" size=12 value="">
         </p>  
         <input type="button" value="Click for Greeting" onclick="greeting()">
          <hr>
          <div id="outputDiv">
         </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: he wants only the name in italics. +1 for using `<style>` and `<script>`

Comment: Thanks, when I saw your post about indenting, I tried to quickly edit mine. :)

Comment: where is the `<style>` I upvoted?

Comment: Citing my comment #2 for the reason for refactoring :-) : "... which of course assumes there _are_ lines and it's not just an unreadable blob of tags running like a freight train across the whole screen"

Comment: Please change the `<i>` to `<em>`. I'll be satisfied with `<em>` :-)

Comment: I chose not to use <em> if that's ok? :)

Answer (score 1):

The tag for italics is `<i>`. You can wrap it around an element to make it appear in italics.
`your name is <i> unknown to us </i>`

**Don't use this tag!**

---

This is acceptable for (1) applications where you need to save each byte, or (2) situations where you need to support ancient browsers like Netscape 1.0. 
 Even email clients support the `<em>` tag or embedded CSS.

A better way is to use the `<em>` tag. 
 It means "emphasize". Most browsers display such text in italics. The difference is with browsers that can't render italics. When such a browser encounters `<i>` it skips the tag and renders its contents without effect. When it encounters `<em>` it emphasizes the text by any means available. Using bold instead, changing the text color, inserting spaces... . For a screen reader, it could mean "slow down by 10% and increase the volume by 5%".

The modern way is to tag by semantics, and style by CSS:

```
your name is <span class="name"> unknown to us </span>
```

and in a separate CSS file

```
span.name { font-style: italic; }
```